# R subset dataframe, skip part of interval

Tags: r, subset, intervals, cut, between

I'm tryng to **subset** my total data (including all the other varibales) to an **interval** of zipcodes **EXCLUDING** a certain part of that interval. Quite new to R and can't get it to work. (Zipcode = postnr)

I have over 100 000 zipcodes (postnr) and want all values for individs in zipcode 10 000-12 999 and 15 600 - 16 800 in my dataset

#### Attempt 1

```
Datan <- subset(Data2, Data2$postnr >= 10000 & Data2$postnr <= 16880) 

Datant <- subset(Datan, Datan$postnr >= 15600 & Datan$postnr < 13000)
```

Datan returns 31 3000 obs in 26 variabels and Datant  returns 0 obs in 26 variabels..

#### Attempt 2

```
attach(Data2)

Data5 <- Data2 %>% filter(between(postnr, 10000, 12999) & between(postnr, 15600, 16880))
```

Data 5 returns 0 obsverations...

I have thousands of values for all my variables inside those intervals. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For `Data5` try replacing the `&` (and) with the pipe `|` (or).

Answer (score 2):

If you think about *and* versus *or* you have gotten it. As it is, you're really close!

Can a number be between 1 and 2 *and* 3 and 5? Nope. But if I said, can a number be between 1 and 2 *or* 3 and 5? Yup.

---

Updated

---

For `subset`:

```
Datan <- subset(Data2, postnr >= 10000 & postnr <= 13000 | 
   postnr >= 15600 & postnr < 16800)
```

Where that verticle pipe: | means 'or'.

For `dplyr`:

(I assume it's `dplyr` with `filter`.) You don't need to `attach` the data, it will extract the variable names from `Data2` if it's in the pipe (which it is).

```
Data5 <- Data2 %>% filter(between(postnr, 10000, 12999) |
    between(postnr, 15600, 16880))
```

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea R had an OR command and suddenly my life is so much easier.

Comment: Update : The last Data5 between code works exactly as intended and ingnores all values between 13000-15599.   But the First Datan code pulls all individuals between 10 000- 16 800 Including the unwanted intervall.

Comment: That's because that's what you coded in the `subset` call.  I just grabbed what you had and didn't even think about it. RIght now it states give me a number that's greater than 10K and less than 16.8K in the first part of the or statement; the second part says give me a number greater than 15.6K and less than 13K (of which no number will satisfy this criteria). It looks like @Mario has already rewritten it.

Answer (score 1):

I have no data, so I can not properly test this, but the following should work.
Note the or operator (|) to specify two different conditions.

```
 library(data.table)
 dt <- as.data.table(Data2)
 dt[(postnr>10000&postnr<13000)|(postnr>15600&postnr<=16880),]
```

Comment: Your code also worked exactly as intended. Thank you.